# checking values against an array

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie struggling with Angular JS.

I am trying to make a questionaire and have the following code but keep getting the feedback for incorrect no matter what I try.

I have assigned a numeric value to each of four buttons, the titles of which are being pulled through from an array. I want to check the value of the selected button against the correct answer in the array. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

```
HTML

<div id="ansblock">
        <button type="button"  ng-click="myAnswer=0">{{options [0]}} </button>
        <button type="button"  ng-click="myAnswer=1">{{options [1]}}</button>
        <button type="button"  ng-click="myAnswer=2">{{options [2]}}</button>
        <button type="button"  ng-click="myAnswer=3">{{options [3]}}</button>          

<p>Test to show button click value working {{myAnswer}}</p>  

 </div>

<button ng-click="checkAnswer()">Submit</button>

<span ng-show="correctAns">That is correct!</span>
<span ng-show="!correctAns">Sorry, that is an incorrect answer.</span>




    JS:


 var app = angular.module('quizApp', []);

app.directive('quiz', function (quizFactory) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.start = function () {
                scope.id = 0;
                scope.quizOver = false;
                scope.inProgress = true;
                scope.getQuestion();
            };

            scope.reset = function () {
                scope.inProgress = false;
                scope.score = 0;
            }

            scope.getQuestion = function () {
                var q = quizFactory.getQuestion(scope.id);
                if (q) {
                    scope.question = q.question;
                    scope.options = q.options;
                    scope.answer = q.answer;
                    scope.answerMode = true;
                } else {
                    scope.quizOver = true;
                }
            };

            scope.checkAnswer = function () {          

                var ans = $('scope.myAnswer').val();

                if(ans==scope.options[scope.answer]) {
                    scope.score++;
                    scope.correctAns = true;
                } else {
                    scope.correctAns = false;
                }
                scope.answerMode = false;
            };

            scope.nextQuestion = function () {
                scope.id++;
                scope.getQuestion();
            }
            scope.reset();
        }
    }
});

app.factory('quizFactory', function () {
    var questions = [
        {
            question: "Which of the following is a WW2 fighter?",
            options: ["Albatross", "Concorde", "Spitfire", "Mirage"],
            answer: 2
        },
        {
            question: "When was the Great Fire of London?",
            options: ["1666", "1966", "1844", "1235"],
            answer: 0
        },
        {
            question: "Which group is a Swedish pop band?",
            options: ["Eagles", "Led Zeppelin", "Beatles", "Abba"],
            answer: 3
        },
        {
            question: "Which city is the capita of Australia?",
            options: ["Canberra", "Sydney", "Melbourne", "Hobart"],
            answer: 0
        },
        {
            question: "Which brand does not make motorcycles?",
            options: ["BMW", "Mercedes", "Kawasaki", "Honda"],
            answer: 1
        }
    ];

    return {
        getQuestion: function (id) {
            if (id < questions.length) {
                return questions[id];
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: can you update the json format of the object?

Comment: please correct, it's if(ans==.. and not If (ans ==..

Comment: It should be $scope

Comment: Thanks. I changed to ' if(ans==' but still the same problem and replacing all instances of scope with $scope caused the submit button to stop working.

Comment: Could you complete the js code? It's missing variable declarations

Comment: I'v added the complete JS code

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way;  It's a bad idea to mix angular and jQuery together.  This line of code `var ans = $('scope.myAnswer').val();` in particular makes no real sense.  You shouldn't need to use jQuery to get the value of `myAnswer`.

Comment: That's the line I'm having trouble with. I want to take the 'ng-click="myAnswer=0" in the HTML for example and see if it matches the numeric value in the correct answer.

Comment: so does `ans = scope.myAnswer;` not work?

Comment: changing 'var ans=scope.myAnswer'   to   'ans = scope.myAnswer;' has no effect. It just keeps telling me the same: I have the incorrect answer when I have the right one selected.

Comment: Your directives are to attached to your tamplate, scope.checkAnswer is never called

Comment: It's in the template here:  `<button ng-click="checkAnswer()" ng-show="answerMode">Submit</button>.`      I have got it working by using this: `ans = scope.myAnswer;            
                if(ans==[scope.answer]) {`         However, if I use the following it will not work :  `if(ans==scope.options[scope.answer]) {`